# De un origen desopilante

Tags: etimología, significado, francés

Leyendo un trino en el fin de semana éste decía: «se mostraba un *desopilante video*». Al ir al DLE para resolver la duda inmediata encuentro como significado:

> [**desopilante**](https://dle.rae.es/desopilante)
>
> 1. adj. Festivo, divertido, que produce mucha risa.

La etimología [entregada](https://definiciona.com/desopilante/) indica que viene de desopilar (sinónimo de destapar) y -nte. La palabra es *reciente* según el mapa de diccionarios, pues aparece a partir del diccionario de 1992 y el CORDE no da referencias de un corte festivo a la palabra. ¿De dónde surge el significado festivo de la palabra y cuál es el origen de la misma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta definición viene del francés [*désopiler / désopilant*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9sopilant):

> ***DESOPILANTE.** adj. Galicismo por jocoso, festivo, divertido.
>
> **DESOPILAR.** tr. Curar la opilación. Ú t. c. r. || *****Galicismo por hacer reír. || *****r. Galicismo por desternillarse de risa.
>
> - DRAE (1927)

> **ETIM. E HIST.** Préstamo semántico del francés *désopiler* (DMILE y DGLE), forma
>   verbal que, en esta lengua, cobra el significado figurado de 'hacer reír' en 1690
>   (ROBHIST). ᭹ Se incorpora esta acepción en el DMILE de 1927 como galicismo
>   por 'hacer reír' y, con esta misma forma, figura en las siguientes ediciones de
>   este diccionario.
>
> - [*Presencia del francés en el español peninsular contemporáneo*](https://is.muni.cz/el/1421/podzim2015/SJ0B775/um/8084102/51035205/C.Curell_Presencia_del_frances_en_el_espanol.txt), DOLORES CORBELLA DÍAZ (2004)